# Wordpress in sub directory wp-admin problem

Tags: wp-admin, htaccess, directory, apache

I have WordPress 3.3.1 installed in a sub directory on my site just to use as a staging test site. It seems the root sites `.htaccess` is creating problems for Wordpress wp-admin page. I've set the `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` to point correctly to the sub directory url.

If I haven't got any `.htaccess` inside my subdirectory (wp root) = wp admin (login page) works.

If I add a `.htaccess` like below, the page works and if you are logged in to wp-admin it sort of works **BUT** every time you try to save something = blank page,
if you **aren't** logged in and try to login = blank page.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subcataloged/cliens-wp/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

## Summary:

[.htaccess in wp root (www.domain.com/sub/cat/)] == Site (except wp-admin) works as expected.

[No htaccess] == Site CSS, images, js is rewritten incorrectly to the root folders, Wp-admin works fine.

How can I solve this? Is there a `.htaccess` for WP 3.3.1 I can use?

This is my `.htaccess` for my **OTHER WEB ROOT** site (not WP):

```
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag

# cache images/pdf/css/js docs for 10 days = 864000, 31536000 = 1 year
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate"
  #Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>

# cache html/htm/xml/txt diles for 2 days
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript text/css application/x- javascript application/javascript image/x-icon
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip


# -FrontPage-
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#Gamla sidor gör rewrite till nya:
RewriteRule ^nyheter/$ %{SCRIPT_URI}senaste-projekt/ [R]
RewriteRule ^webben/$ %{SCRIPT_URI}tips-for-webben/ [R]
###

RewriteRule ^utvalda-projekt/$ / [L]
RewriteRule ^senaste-projekt/$ %{SCRIPT_URI}index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^webbportfolio/$ %{SCRIPT_URI}views/webbport.php [L]
RewriteRule ^universitetet/$ %{SCRIPT_URI}views/uniport.php [L]
RewriteRule ^kontakta-mig/$ %{SCRIPT_URI}views/kontakt.php [L]

RewriteRule ^presentation/$ pres.php [L]
RewriteRule ^tips-for-webben/$ webben.php [L]
RewriteRule ^CV/$ views/cv.php [L]
RewriteRule ^CV-en/$ views/cv_en.php [L]

RewriteRule ^goeco/$ goeco.php [L]
RewriteRule ^eld/$ fire.php [L]
RewriteRule ^movie-night/$ movienight/ [R]


RewriteRule ^webbtutorials/$ tutorials.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sokhjalp/$ search.php [L]
RewriteRule ^valj_ratt_webblasare/$ valja_webblasare.php [L]
RewriteRule ^mina_bloggar/$ blog.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/lightbox/css/(.+)$ %{SCRIPT_URI}/lightbox/css/$2 [R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/lightbox/js/(.+)$ %{SCRIPT_URI}/lightbox/js/$2 [R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/portfolio/(.+)$ %{SCRIPT_URI}portfolio/$2 [R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/css/(.+)$ %{SCRIPT_URI}css/$2 [R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/img/(.+)$ %{SCRIPT_URI}/img/$2 [R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/grafik/(.+)$ %{SCRIPT_URI}/grafik/$2 [R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/js/(.+)$ %{SCRIPT_URI}/js/$2 [R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/uni_portfolio/(.+)$ %{SCRIPT_URI}/uni_portfolio/$2 [R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/dokument/(.+)$ %{SCRIPT_URI}/dokument/$2 [R]

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
```

Comment: Stupid question, but is "clients" mis-spelled as "cliens" in RewriteBase /subcataloged/cliens-wp/?

Comment: No it's the company name :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing some rules in your WP .htaccess file.  I show mine below.  Notice the rules for wp-admin, add them to your file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subcataloged/cliens-wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Are you sure you updated the RewriteBase above to match your directory?  My htaccess file is almost exactly as your, but adds rules for wp-admin and other directories/files.  Here is another way to see the proper rules, remove the WP .htaccess file, then look go to the Network console - http://mysite.domain.com/subcataloged/cliens-wp/wp-admin/network/setup.php